# Scanning line by line with Windows.Media.Ocr engine

Tags: vb.net, ocr, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I'm using Windows.Media.OCR engine to scan these two lines

[image]

But the software scan them like that:

[image]

While I'm expecting it to scan like:

> KIBA/USDT 0.00003826 6.31M KIBA 241.68459400 USDT

> KIBA/USDT 0.00003470 17.13M KIBA 594.48387000 USDT

The code I'm using is:

```
'require references: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd"
'"C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll"
' and windows 10 sdk
Imports Windows.Media.Ocr
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim softwareBmp As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap
        Using bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(PictureBox1.Left, PictureBox1.Top))
                g.CopyFromScreen(pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
                Using memStream = New Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream()
                    bmp.Save(memStream.AsStream(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
                    Dim decoder As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder = Await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(memStream)
                    softwareBmp = Await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Dim ocrEng = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(New Windows.Globalization.Language("en-US"))

        Dim languages As IReadOnlyList(Of Windows.Globalization.Language) = ocrEng.AvailableRecognizerLanguages
        For Each language In languages
            Console.WriteLine(language.LanguageTag)
        Next
        Dim r = ocrEng.RecognizerLanguage
        Dim n = ocrEng.MaxImageDimension

        Dim ocrResult = Await ocrEng.RecognizeAsync(softwareBmp)
        RichTextBox1.Text = ocrResult.Text
        
    End Sub
End Class
```

Which kind of change does this code needs in order to scan by row and not by column?

edit:
Binary: [code](https://hexed.it#base64+lzjb:-Senza%20Titolo-;ADAxLTA0IDE5ADowNTo1OAlMAGltaXQJS0lCAEEvVVNEVAkwBC4wAAEzNTk5CYAxMDQuMUsgBBwACTMuNzQ2NTUQOTAwICAnJQlDAGFuY2VsDQowCjEgVjJkVjIzLjIEMk0MVjgzNS44oDk2NTQyTFgA/AH//EL8QvxC/EL8QvxC/EL8Qj/8QvxC/EL8QvxC/EIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)

so there is 0D 0A between rows

The complete rows image:
[image]

but I didn't post it before cause I anyway I will need to scan only from 0.000038 ecc to 0.0000%

Comment: I'll delete the comments too and I'll try !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose to act on the output string instead of tackling the OCR API.

*Fixing the issue within the OCR API would probably be a superior solution if possible, but I could not get your code properly referenced in my system.*

So you can add this function to transpose the string

```vb
Private Function transpose(input As String) As String
    Dim numberOfColumns = 4 ' this must be known and could be a parameter to this function
    Dim fixedInput = input.Replace(" KIBA", "|KIBA").Replace(" USDT", "|USDT")
    Dim splitInput = fixedInput.Split(" "c)
    Dim numberOfWords = splitInput.Count()
    Dim numberOfRows = numberOfWords / numberOfColumns 
    Dim words As New List(Of String)()
    For row = 0 To numberOfRows - 1
        For col = 0 To numberOfColumns - 1
            words.Add(splitInput(CInt(row + numberOfRows * col)))
        Next
    Next
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For i = 0 To words.Count() - 1
        sb.Append(words(i).Replace("|", " "))
        If (i <> words.Count() - 1) Then
            sb.Append(If((i + 1) Mod numberOfColumns = 0, Environment.NewLine, vbTab))
        End If
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Simply pass your ocr output string through it. Here it is called in your code

```vb
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim softwareBmp As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap
    Using bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(PictureBox1.Left, PictureBox1.Top))
            g.CopyFromScreen(pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
            Using memStream = New Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream()
                bmp.Save(memStream.AsStream(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
                Dim decoder As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder = Await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(memStream)
                softwareBmp = Await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim ocrEng = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(New Windows.Globalization.Language("en-US"))
    Dim languages As IReadOnlyList(Of Windows.Globalization.Language) = ocrEng.AvailableRecognizerLanguages
    For Each language In languages
        Console.WriteLine(language.LanguageTag)
    Next
    Dim r = ocrEng.RecognizerLanguage
    Dim n = ocrEng.MaxImageDimension
    Dim ocrResult = Await ocrEng.RecognizeAsync(softwareBmp)
    RichTextBox1.Text = transpose(ocrResult.Text)
End Sub
```

I tested with this function

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim input = "0.00003599 0.00003599 104.1K KIBA 23.22M KIBA 3.74655900 USDT 835.89654200 USDT 0.0000% 0.0000%"
    Dim output = transpose(input)
End Sub
```

Input:

> 0.00003599 0.00003599 104.1K KIBA 23.22M KIBA 3.74655900 USDT 835.89654200 USDT 0.0000% 0.0000%

Output:

> 0.00003599 104.1K KIBA 3.74655900 USDT 0.0000%
>
> 0.00003599  23.22M KIBA 835.89654200 USDT   0.0000%

Note you need to fix your string to temporarily replace any sentence with multiple words by replacing the space   with a pipe `|` so they are not split, and if you encounter more examples of this you can continue adding `Replace` according to the code. If the pipe turns out to be a valid character replace it with some other character you will never see.

```vb
Dim fixedInput = input.Replace(" KIBA", "|KIBA").Replace(" USDT", "|USDT")
...
sb.Append(words(i).Replace("|", " "))
```

Another solution, again working on the incorrect string by transposing, but this time the output will be a class which you can work with.

Make a class to represent your data

```vb
Public Class KibaClass
    Public Property Price As Decimal
    Public Property VolumeKIBA As Decimal
    Public Property VolumeUSDT As Decimal
    Public Property Percent As Decimal
End Class
```

And a different function to parse into this class

```vb
Private Function transposeToClass(input As String) As IEnumerable(Of KibaClass)
    Dim numberOfColumns = 4
    Dim fixedInput = input.Replace(" KIBA", "|KIBA").Replace(" USDT", "|USDT").Trim()
    Dim splitInput = fixedInput.Split(" "c)
    Dim numberOfWords = splitInput.Count()
    Dim numberOfRows = numberOfWords / numberOfColumns ' 2
    Dim words As New List(Of String)()
    For row = 0 To numberOfRows - 1
        For col = 0 To numberOfColumns - 1
            words.Add(splitInput(CInt(row + numberOfRows * col)))
        Next
    Next
    Dim kibas As New List(Of KibaClass)()
    For row = 0 To numberOfRows - 1
        Dim rowOffset = CInt(row * numberOfColumns)
        Dim kiba = New KibaClass With {
            .Percent = CDec(words(3 + rowOffset).Replace("%", "")) / 100,
            .Price = CDec(words(0 + rowOffset))}

        Dim multiplier As Double

        Dim splitVolume = words(1 + rowOffset).Split("|"c)(0)
        Dim lastChar = Convert.ToChar(splitVolume.Last())
        Dim volume = splitVolume

        If Not Char.IsDigit(lastChar) Then
            volume = splitVolume.Substring(0, splitVolume.Length - 1)
            Select Case lastChar.ToString().ToUpper()
                Case "T"
                    multiplier = 1000000000.0
                Case "M"
                    multiplier = 1000000.0
                Case "K"
                    multiplier = 1000.0
                Case Else
                    multiplier = 1.0
            End Select
        End If
        kiba.VolumeKIBA = CDec(CDbl(volume) * multiplier)

        splitVolume = words(2 + rowOffset).Split("|"c)(0)
        lastChar = Convert.ToChar(splitVolume.Last())
        volume = splitVolume
        If Not Char.IsDigit(lastChar) Then
            volume = splitVolume.Substring(0, splitVolume.Length - 1)
            Select Case lastChar.ToString().ToUpper()
                Case "T"
                    multiplier = 1000000000.0
                Case "M"
                    multiplier = 1000000.0
                Case "K"
                    multiplier = 1000.0
                Case Else
                    multiplier = 1.0
            End Select
        End If
        kiba.VolumeUSDT = CDec(CDbl(volume) * multiplier)

        kibas.Add(kiba)
    Next
    Return kibas
End Function
```

```vb
Dim output1 = transposeToClass(input)
```

This holds an `IEnumerable` of your class which you can enumerate into multiple instances of that object with properties in the proper format representing the columns you originally OCR'd.

Comment: That's seriously amazing and I couldn't be more grateful for the stunning help you gave me! That's even better of what I thought off!!  I would like to ask you , if it 's possible, since words are in a list of strings, could I consider the last value ( 0.000%) as a single string? for example, if last value is equal to 100 then and i'll do whatever I need to do.
Many Thanks and hope to cross paths with you again in SO!

Comment: @replik appended the answer with another solution for outputting a class you can process. Although you asked for a string, I specifically avoided strings in favor of Decimals, which more accurately represents your data.